# How to correctly merge two arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, merge

I have following array with objects in it:

```js
[
  {
    name: "test",
    sub: {
      name: "asdf",
      sub: {}
    }
  },
  {
    name: "models",
    sub: {}
  }
]
```

And i have also folowing object:

```js
{
  name: "test",
  sub: {
    name: "asdf",
    sub: {
      name: "inside_asdf",
      sub: {}
    }
  }
}
```

Now i want to somehow merge the two so that i get an array that looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    name: "test",
    sub: {
      name: "asdf",
      sub: {
        name: "inside_asdf",
        sub: {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    name: "models",
    sub: {}
  }
]
```

The problem is i don't know how to do that. Also i want that this works with any array depth so if i want to merge an array to the sub of "inside_asdf" it also works.
Hope someone could help me. I also already tried Object.merge but this doesn't output the required result.
I am thankful for every info or solution.
Thanks in advance.

##FIX##

I marked the correct answer below. However because i programmed the whole application in react with typescript i found a nother solution to this problem.

Comment: 2nd is not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Updated answer gives outcome what you desire, however it is, using jQuery, prototype $.extend.

Not that I wrapped once again, the aaaa with `[]` array tag, since it needs to have same structure.

Full code to acheve what you want:

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "test",
    sub: {
      name: "asdf",
      sub: {}
    }
  },
  {
    name: "models",
    sub: {}
  }
];

var aaaa = [{
    name: "test",
    sub: {
      name: "asdf",
      sub: {
        name: "inside_asdf",
        sub: {}
      }
    }
  }];


console.log($.extend({}, data, aaaa));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: According to the OP the third object should be combined in the first, and only the `sub` property needs to be appended

Comment: Ah shoot, @KunalMukherjee You are totally right, I missed the sub part. I'll fix it right away.

Comment: Sorry to mention that but i forgot a little bit of code. Does it also work if the "sub:{}" looks like "sub:[{}]" ?

Comment: Golden rule, consistency is the key, if you are planning to hold multiple sub elements in sub:, then keep the array structure "[{}]", if you make one with multiple and other one not, still add [] to it, make it consistant.

Comment: @Max check the edited answer, it should provide you with what you need.